# SpringBatch : Unable to detect database type

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am creating a very basic Hello World Spring Batch application in Springboot.
But springboot is not able to connect to Postgres database.

My postgres is running in docker locally.
Although same application is working with H2 database.

Is there any other property I am missing for Postgres?

Getting below error:

```
     .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.6.10)

2022-08-12 15:54:34.503  INFO 32118 --- [           main] c.e.chapter04.Chapter04Application       : Starting Chapter04Application using Java 11.0.11 on PSINGHHH with PID 32118 (/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter04/target/classes started by psingh6 in /Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter04)
2022-08-12 15:54:34.508  INFO 32118 --- [           main] c.e.chapter04.Chapter04Application       : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-08-12 15:54:35.433  INFO 32118 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-12 15:54:35.446  INFO 32118 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-12 15:54:35.949  INFO 32118 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-12 15:54:35.958  INFO 32118 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-12 15:54:35.958  INFO 32118 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-12 15:54:36.084  INFO 32118 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-12 15:54:36.084  INFO 32118 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1451 ms
2022-08-12 15:54:36.177  INFO 32118 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-12 15:54:36.185  WARN 32118 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
2022-08-12 15:54:36.187  INFO 32118 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-12 15:54:36.199  INFO 32118 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-12 15:54:36.227 ERROR 32118 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at com.example.chapter04.Chapter04Application.main(Chapter04Application.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:132) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.lambda$resolveAll$0(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:121) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.resolveSchemaLocations(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.getSettings(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.<init>(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.batchDataSourceInitializer(BatchAutoConfiguration.java:117) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.10.jar:2.6.10]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

application.properites

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5439/spring_batch
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=default
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>chapter04</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chapter04</name>
    <description>chapter04</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5439/spring_batch
```

The database type should be postgresql, not postgres.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked ! Such an obvious error I could not notice . The error message should be improved .